# getting NSArray length/count - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, count, nsarray

Well I've looked at similar problems over the site but haven't reached a solution thus far so I must be doing something wrong.

Essentially, I am importing a text file, then splitting each line into an element of an array. Since the text file will be updated etc.. I won't every know the exact amount of lines in the file and therefore how many elements in the array. I know in Java you can do .length() etc.. and supposedly in Objective C  you can use 'count' but i'm having no luck returning the length of my array... suggestions?

> ```
>  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"allshows" 
>                                                      ofType:@"txt"];
> ```

```
 NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];  

NSUInteger *elements = [lines count];
NSLog(@"Number of Shows : ", elements);
```

and what is being output is NOTHING. as in "Number of Shows :  " - blank, like it didn't even count at all.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing the format string placeholder. It should be:

```
NSLog(@"Number of shows: %lu", elements);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a format specifier to print an integer (`%d`):

```
NSLog(@"Number of Shows : %d", elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your other post, it seems like you are a Java developer. In Java's System.out, you just append the variables. In Objective-C, I suggest you look at "print format specifiers". Objective-C uses the same format.